# Android Application EULA with no company?

Tags: android, eula

I found several EULA samples in stack overflow but in all of them it displays company information. I am alone and I want to publich a paid application in android's market.

Do I need to "build" a company?
What text should I put in EULA?

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found this one!

```
END USER LICENSE FOR ANDROID { SOFTWARE NAME } SOFTWARE
PLEASE READ THIS DOCUMENT CAREFULLY BEFORE USING THIS SOFTWARE. THIS LICENSE PROVIDES IMPORTANT INFORMATION CONCERNING THE SOFTWARE, PROVIDES YOU WITH A LICENSE TO USE THE SOFTWARE AND CONTAINS WARRANTY AND LIABILITY INFORMATION.
BY USING THE SOFTWARE, YOU ARE ACCEPTING THE SOFTWARE "AS IS" AND AGREEING TO BE BOUND BY THE TERMS OF THIS LICENSE AGREEMENT.
IN NO ENVENT WILL THE AUTHORS BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY DAMASES ARISING FROM THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO DO SO, DO NOT USE THE SOFTWARE.

1. Terms of License
This license allows you to:
(a) use the Software on a single device; and
If you wish to use the Software on more than one device, you must license another copy of the
Software.

2. Restrictions on Use
Unless { Owner's name } (Owner) has authorized you to distribute the Software, you shall not make or distribute copies of the Software or transfer the Software from one device to another. You shall not decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, include in other software, or translate the Software, or use the Software for any commercial purposes. You shall not modify, alter, change or otherwise make any modification to the Software or create derivative works based upon the Software. You shall not rent, lease, resell, sub-license, assign, distribute or otherwise transfer the Software or this license. Any attempt to do so shall be void and of no effect.

3. Ownership
This license provides you with limited rights to use the Software. The Owner retains all ownership, right, title and interest in, to and of the Software and all copies of it. All rights not specifically granted in this license, including domestic and international copyrights, are reserved by the Owner.

4. Proprietary Markings
The Owner's logos, product names, manuals, documentation, and other support materials are either patented, copyrighted, trademarked, constitute valuable trade secrets (whether or not any portion of them may be copyrighted or patented) or are otherwise proprietary to the Owner. You shall not remove or obscure the Owner's copyright, trade mark or other proprietary notices from any of the materials contained in this package or downloaded together with the Software.

5. Disclaimer of Warranties and Technical Support
The Software is provided to you after paying a licence and on an "AS IS" basis, without any technical support or warranty of any kind including, without limitation, any warranty or condition of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and non-infringement.

SOME JURISDICTIONS DO NOT ALLOW THE EXCLUSION OF IMPLIED WARRANTIES, SO THE ABOVE EXCLUSION MAY NOT APPLY TO YOU. YOU MAY ALSO HAVE OTHER LEGAL RIGHTS WHICH VARY FROM JURISDICTION TO JURISDICTION.
```

Try to change something so it becomes a litle different :)

Comment: We may use an EULA like this one or simply use the licence that google provides! (the later option is the simpler one and the better one because, usually, we don't know nothing bout the law!)

Comment: what is 'the licence that google provides' you are referring to?

Comment: when you publish an app in android market it specifies that somewhere :)

Comment: Are you saying that actually we don't really need a EULA, as Google provide good one when you publish?

Comment: @noelicus when putting an app on android market, yes! :)

Comment: Do you know why Google in [their documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html) state "Consider preparing an End User License Agreement (EULA) for your application. A EULA can help protect your person, organization, and intellectual property, and we recommend that you provide one with your application."? That doesn't quite fit with them providing one for you (they don't mention it for a start!)

Comment: @noelicus When you publish you may not have a EULA but they provide one licence that acts as it. I don't recall exactly when but they do!

Comment: @aF.  "licence" is misspelled in section 5.  'we dun no nutin bout the law!' ;)

Comment: Where should I put this when I upload my app? Thanks so much, I'm looking forward to publishing my first app!

Answer (score 9):

I used this free EULA generator:

http://kuikie.com/tools/eula_generator/application.php

You can put in an your individual name or your company name.

Comment: This link is only for computer software, not for android software.

Comment: @Simon Android actually runs on computers.

Answer (score 5):

In response to the first question, I would recommend that you look for a "click-wrap" EULA template.  It allows you to "fill in the blanks".

I am extremely curious about the EULA agreements involving Google.  The main reason I say this is because I am not sure if these agreements are intended to protect Google itself, rather than the publisher.

Google specifically states: "Consider preparing an End User License Agreement (EULA) for your application. A EULA can help protect your person, organization, and intellectual property, and we recommend that you provide one with your application."